# My wireless card is stuck on channel -1 when I'm trying to use aireplay-ng

Tags: wireless, intel, wireless-access-point, intel-wireless

I have an Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev 35). I've put my card into monitor mode, started airodump-ng, etc. Even if I set my channel to 6 (happens to be the one of my access point) when I go to use aireplay-ng, it stops and says that "The access point you're trying to do whatever with is set on channel 6, but your card is on channel -1. I'm not really sure why it's doing this.

Comment: Can't do a full post at the moment but this is likely either because your driver needs patching or because network manager is locking the channel. Kill network-manager and try again.

Comment: I thought I patched the driver successfully. I'll try the network-manager thing in the morning :3

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it. I had to patch the driver with the negative 1 patch. I was applying the patch incorrectly though. Patch syntax is patch -p(one) not patch -pl.